# Sync() method to update pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, synchronization, laravel-5

I'm trying to update my pivot table `approvals_document` with a column `isApprove` which is a extra column. I used this method so it will not duplicated in my pivot table.

View

```
@foreach ($pendingDocuments as $list)
    <form class = "form-inline" id="submitMe" method = "post" action = "{{ url('documents/pending') }}">

        <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "{{ $list->id }}">

        <div class = "radio">
            <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showApprove()" name = "status" value = "1"> Approve</label>
        </div>


        <div class = "radio">
            <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showReject()" name = "status" value = "2"> Reject</label>
        </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function updateApprovalsDocument(Request $request, $id)
{
    $document = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('approvals_document.id', 'approvals_document.isApprove')
        ->where('approvals_document.id', '=', $id)
        ->first();


    foreach($request->status as $status)
    {
        $document->sentToApprovers()->sync([$status => ['isApprove' => $request->status, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]], true);
    }


    return redirect()->back();
 }
```

`$status` here is the name of the Radio Button in my view. Do I need to used `first()` method here to update my record using radio button?

routes

```
Route::get('/documents/pending',
[
   'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@documentsSentForApproval',
   'as' => 'document.pending',
]);

Route::post('/documents/pending',
[
   'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateApprovalsDocument',
    'as' => 'document.pending',
]);
```

Error

```
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::updateApprovalsDocument()
```

But I already define `$id` and `Request $request` in my parameter and imported at the top the `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` Any help how can I solve this problem?

UPDATE

View

```
<form class = "form-inline" id="submitMe" method = "post" action = "{{ route('documents/pending',['id' => [$list->id]]) }}">

            <div class = "radio">
                <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showApprove()" name = "status" value = "1"> Approve</label>
            </div>


            <div class = "radio">
                <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showReject()" name = "status" value = "2"> Reject</label>
            </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
```

Controller

```
public function updateApprovalsDocument(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id'); //add this to get the id
    $document = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('approvals_document.id', 'approvals_document.isApprove')
        ->where('approvals_document.id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

    $document->sentToApprovers()->sync([$request->status => ['isApprove' => $request->status, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]], true);
}
```

Comment: can you post the route which calls this method

Comment: @jaysingkar Hello! I updated my post please see.

Comment: `$id` parameter in your method is not getting passed from the route as it does not have the parameter. Try removing $id from your method's argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$id` from your method's argument list.

```
public function updateApprovalsDocument(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $document = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->where('approvals_document.id', '=', $id)
        ->update(['isApprove' => $request->status, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]]);

    return redirect()->back();
 }
```

Comment: Why should I remove `$id` in my parameter? I tried your solution but it says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: for `$id` to work, you need to add parameter to your route like `
'/documents/pending/{id}'` and update your form's action `action = "{{ route('documents/pending',[$list->id]) }}"`

Comment: btw, `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` is not due to id, the `$status` is not an array and also you are rewriting it in your for each.

Comment: @Francisunoxx why are you looping through the `$status` ? It is not an array but a single value. remove the for each. check my update